# Finding a pattern, then executing a line change only after the pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file of the like:

```
H 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
C 1 2 3 4
 $END

 $EFRAG
COORD=CART
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
O 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
O 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
```

I want to remove the column "1" from the lines *only* after the $EFRAG line. and add a label to the O H H as well. My expected output is:

```
H 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
C 1 2 3 4
 $END

 $EFRAG
COORD=CART
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
Oa  2 3 4
Hb  2 3 4
Hc  2 3 4
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
Oa  2 3 4
Hb  2 3 4
Hc  2 3 4
```

I'm new to coding in bash, and I'm not quite sure where to start.

I was thinking of piping a grep command to a sed command, but I'm not sure how that syntax would look. Am also trying to learn awk, but that syntax is even more confusing to me. Currently trying to read a book on it's capabilities.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

L

Comment: In `sed` you can specify a line range where commands should be executed, and you can use pattern matching in the range, like `/\$EFRAG/,$` will operate from the `$EFRAG` line to the end of the file. Is that enough of a hint for you to try to code it?

Comment: With the successive changes I would definitely go with Awk. Put the suffixes `"a", "b", "c"` in an array and loop over that array on every line after a `/FRAGNAME/`, starting when you have seen `/\$EFRAG/`. This sounds like something you could do as your fourth or fifth Awk exercise after 30-60 minutes of learning the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `awk` processing:

```
awk '$0~/\$EFRAG/ {
    start = 1;  # marker denoting the needed block
    split("a b c", suf);  # auxiliary array of suffixes
}
start {
    if (/^FRAGNAME/) idx = 1;  # encountering subblock
    if (/^[OH]/) {  # if starting with O or H char
        $2 = "";
        $1 = $1 suf[idx++];
    }
}1' test.txt
```

---

```
H 1 2 3 4
H 1 2 3 4
C 1 2 3 4
 $END

 $EFRAG
COORD=CART
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
Oa  2 3 4
Hb  2 3 4
Hc  2 3 4
FRAGNAME=H2ODFT
Oa  2 3 4
Hb  2 3 4
Hc  2 3 4
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! syntax starting to make sense.

Comment: @EdMorton, I knew you will review to the last detail )

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The `script.ed` (name it to your own hearts content)  something like:

```
/\$EFRAG$/;$g/^O /s/^\([^ ]*\) [^ ]* \(.*\)$/\1a  \2/\
/^H /s/^\([^ ]*\) [^ ]* \(.*\)$/\1b  \2/\
/^H /s/^\([^ ]*\) [^ ]* \(.*\)$/\1c  \2/
,p
Q
```

---

Now run

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is required.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1,/\$EFRAG/b;/^O/{N;N;s/^(O) \S+(.*\nH) \S+(.*\nH) \S+/\1a\2b\3c/}' file
```

Do not process lines from the start of the file until after encountering one containing `$EFRAG`.

If a line begins `O`, append the next two lines and then using pattern matching and back references, format those lines accordingly.